# How to import type from react-pdf?

Tags: react-pdf

`react-pdf` 7.6.0 has `Document` component with a `file` prop of type `File`.

This `File` type is defined in `node_modules/react-pdf/dist/esm/shared/types.d.ts` like this,

```js
export type File = string | ArrayBuffer | Blob | Source | null;
```

I want to use the same type in my custom component.

How can I import and use this `File` type in my code? For example, how can I use this `File` type

```js
// import type File from ??

const PdfViewer = ({ file : File }) = {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the File type from react-pdf in your custom component, you need to import it as a type since it's not a regular JavaScript object but a TypeScript type. You can do this by using TypeScript's import type syntax. Here's a way you can import and use the File type in your component,

```
import type { File } from 'react-pdf';

interface PdfViewerProps {
  file: File;
}

const PdfViewer: React.FC<PdfViewerProps> = ({ file }) => {
  

  return (
    //  jsx
  );
};

export default PdfViewer;
```

Comment: Thanks @Faisal but how can I specify the type of the file prop to `File`? I have edited my question for this too.

Comment: See the updated code